# Как вызывать php функцию по таймеру?

Tags: php

Есть php функция `msg_get_messages()`. Возможно ли с помощью php вызывать эту функцию каждые 10 секунд?

Answer (score 1):

С некоторыми неточностями, можно. Используя ф-ю [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php) скрипт будет засыпать ненадолго (в миллисекундах время сна), потом проверять текущее системное время, и если оно кратно 10 секундам (или отличается от него не в пределах погрешности), выполнять рабочую ф-ю. Потом снова засыпать.

Т.к. нежелательно, чтобы скрипт работал бесконечно, можно его работу бить на, скажем, 15-минутные отрезки. По крону каждые 15 минут запускать этот скрипт, а в нём самом следить за тем, чтобы без-10-секунд следующие 15 минут он выполнил рабочую ф-ю последний раз и вышел.

Допустим, ошибаться можно на 200 ms. Тогда `usleep(2E5)` усыпит скрипт на 200ms (0.2 секунды). Простнувшись, надо проверить время ф-ей `microtime(TRUE)` – вернёт системное время с долями секунды как float число.

Этот метод никак не гарантирует, что не проспите очередные 10 секунд – php ведь может притормозить, если, например, система сильна загружена.

Comment: Скрипт должен вызывать ф-цию msg_get_messages() безконечно. С шагом в 10s.

Comment: При бесконечно долго работающем одном скрипте есть риск, что из-за утечки памяти он сожрёт всю доступную и сдохнет. Но раз хотите, просто пусть проверяется текущее время на «расстояние» меньше периода сна до ближайшего, кратного 10 секундам – в таком случае вызывайте вашу `msg_get_messages()`, иначе снова `usleep(2E5)`